# Abstract out repeated code

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code in this event is repeated exactly in two other event handlers.  How do I put the repeated code into a method and call that method from the event handlers so I only have to maintain it in one place?  I'm not sure how to pass the event args to the calling method.

```
 protected void gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {



            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC")) == "Transcript") && 
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == ""))
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC")) == "Certified Diploma") &&
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == ""))
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DOC_TYPE_DESC")) == "Post Graduate conditions") &&
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == ""))

                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: What's the problem to pass e as a parameter to a 4th function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign the same handler to more than one object that is raising events. For example,

```
myGridView1.RowDataBound += gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound;
myGridView2.RowDataBound += gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound;
myGridView3.RowDataBound += gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound;
```

Alternately, just create a method with the same signature as the event handler, and pass in the same arguments:

```
private void RepeatedCodeHandler(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
{
   // Repeated code
}
```

and from your three handlers that are repeating code,

```
protected void gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     // Call method
     RepeatedCodeHandler(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this entire code in a simple method. You can copy the method entirely, change its name, and add calls to it from the event handlers.

But a better way would be to assign this method as the event handler for all three events.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: attach the same event handler to multiple events

```
gvDocAssoc.OnRowDataBound += gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound;
gvDocAssoc.<SecondEvent> += gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound;
```

Option 2: put the code into a method & call the method at the appropriate time in the event handlers

```
protected void gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    set_row_styling(e);
}

private void set_row_styling(GridViewRowEventArgs e){
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
            { 
                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC")) == "Transcript") &&  
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == "")) 
                { 
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
                } 
                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC")) == "Certified Diploma") && 
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == "")) 
                { 
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
                } 

                if ((Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DOC_TYPE_DESC")) == "Post Graduate conditions") && 
                    (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == "")) 

                { 
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
                } 

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```
    bool RowHasError(GridViewRow row, string itemName, string itemValue)
    {
        return (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, itemName)) == itemValue) &&
                   (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "INSTITUTION_CODE")) == "");
    }

    protected void gvDocAssoc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (RowHasError(e.Row, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC", "Transcript") 
                || (RowHasError(e.Row, "DETAIL_TYPE_DESC", "Certified Diploma") 
                || (RowHasError(e.Row, "DOC_TYPE_DESC", "Post Graduate conditions") ) 
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }                
        }
    }
```